# Properly align content in columns

Tags: html, css

That's a layout with which I'm currently dealing.

[image]

I don't have some consistent thoughts about how to properly align content in such columns. Paragraphs always shifted, also height of columns isn't full, guess that I'm missing something. Here is what do I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/scmk01jr/.

```
html, body, .container {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.height-100 {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: Search display:flex and use it to the container, and then, each .s3 add flex:1 and height:100%.... https://jsfiddle.net/scmk01jr/1/

Comment: thanks @Roy, how to then properly align content in this columns?

Comment: add flex-direction: column & justify-content: center to .block. https://jsfiddle.net/scmk01jr/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox might be a good solution here:

https://jsfiddle.net/6c4agx54/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x25" />
      <h6>
        Small Hdr
      </h6>
      <p>
        This is some text below the h6 heading.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x25" />
      <h6>
        Small Hdr
      </h6>
      <p>
        This is some text below the h6 heading.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x25" />
      <h6>
        Small Hdr
      </h6>
      <p>
        This is some text below the h6 heading.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x25" />
      <h6>
        Small Hdr
      </h6>
      <p>
        This is some text below the h6 heading.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;  
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 2.5%;
  padding-right: 2.5%;
  background: #F66A6D;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.col:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F9B7B8;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 17px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Note: I removed the framework you had added to the fiddle - if you can do this with plain HTML and CSS, you should be able to merge them quite easily, and a vanilla version of this serves the community better.